# Should I use prefixfree.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Adding all those vendor prefixes truly is hell. Would adding prefixfree be a great solution?
Basically it is 2kb big and creates all vendor prefixes for you when the browser doesnt support the unprefixed version. Only downside is IF javascript is disabled some css3 elements wont show in older browser...but honestly who has javascript disabled in 2013?

Comment: `"but honestly who has javascript disabled in 2013"` ... I would love to agree with you, unfortunatly, ***A LOT*** of people still cruise with js disabled.

Comment: Isn't it about 1% of users? Just to play the devil's advocate, it seems silly to support a group of users who are a smaller user base than IE 7.

Comment: I would recommend using a css-precompiler like Less or Sass, they let you write mixins which prevents the monotony of re-writing all these prefixes everywhere.

Comment: just a note in case you don't know http://caniuse.com is an extremely useful tool for deciding which prefixes to use.

Comment: It doesn't work in files being called using the `@import` directive. This could also be seen as a good thing because if we're using `@import` to import files, we have a different and even bigger problem in our hands.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I just develop without vendor prefixes, then add them all in later by hand or using a tool like [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/). It seems wasteful to force users to do client-side processing because you were too lazy to give them a page their browser can understand.

That said, if `prefixfree.js` can save you some time *and* your site requires Javascript for other functionality, then by all means use it. Otherwise I would stay away from it.

Comment: With that approach, I'd probably Develop with `prefixfree` so you can X-Browser test, then remove it and add prefixes in before going to production.

Comment: Yeah that would be a good idea

Comment: Ya, because I noticed that by removing all my prefixed version I can reduce my css file by 10kb! and the prefixfree.js is only 2kb. The js will be merged with my other scripts though to reduce http requests. I use javascript for some important functionality so I dont think it will hurt if i use prefixfree`?

Comment: Sure, but there are better ways to optimize your requests like using gzip on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support browsers with JS disabled, then you need a server-side solution.  [Compass](http://compass-style.org) is a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

SublimeText2 auto-completes properties with their prefixes (or maybe its a plugin I have installed?). This *may* be the best option. No added effort, no preproccessor requirement, no JS dependency.

I tried prefixfree a while back, but I remember it failed in some strange situations so I abandoned it.

Comment: Sublime's awesome multi-edit aside, you need to change the value in multiple places -> pain

Comment: With the auto-complete, it auto-splits the cursor. I type box-shadow <tab> 1px 1px 1px #ccc <enter>, and boom! I have -moz-, -webkit-, and *sans-prefix* all set up for me.

Comment: It occurs to me, you mean that after inserting this stuff, you have to change in multiple places. Very true. That's a good point in favor of LESS/SASS/etc..